# how to hide "text" in PowerShell window?

Tags: python-3.x, powershell

Like in Linux, when we perform `sudo` and type password. That time we cannot see the password in the terminal.
I want to do the same thing in the PowerShell window. How can I do that?
(Also suggest python code for it)

Comment: If you want to ask for an *account* including the password in PowerShell you use `Get-Credential`.

Comment: Your subject is quite missleading. You may change it to something with "*sudo*" in it ... or "*asking for password*" or so ...  and it does not make that much sense to have *PowerShell* in the suibject but asking for python help. ;-)

Comment: @Olaf  No, when we type the password in Linux (When it asks for `sudo` permission) then the password is hidden. Is it possible to do in PowerShell also.

Comment: PowerShell does not have a sudo command if this is your question. We use `Get-Credential` to be able to run tasks in another context. If you want to read some text and turn it into a `SecureString` you could use `Read-Host -AsSecureString`

Answer (score 6):

For credentials specifically you should use `Get-Credentials`.

For a general solution, you should use `Read-Host -AsSecureString`. You must then call `ConvertFrom-SecureString` to retrieve the plain text string value.

On Powershell v7.1+, the parameter `Read-Host -MaskInput` exists, which only masks keyboard input.

For impersonation, you will typically want to use `runas.exe`, but in general the Linux security model doesn't match the Windows security model in complete concept or design. That is to say, my response is, "What are you trying to accomplish because it sounds increasingly incorrect?"

For Python, I have no idea. That should be a different question as the answer is wholly unrelated.